# Searching for a particular name in a file, then changing a value associated with it using a function

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary

My program creates files which lists students in a class and their scores. I am trying to make a function which allows the user to edit the score of a particular student inside the appropriate class file. So far, I have been able to create the files and add students and their scores like so:

```
def createClass(chosenclass, data):
    classoptions = 'Class {}'.format(chosenclass)
    with open(f'{classoptions}.txt', '+w') as file:
        for key,value in data.items():
            studentdata = 'Name: {}, Score: {}/100\n'.format(key, value)
            file.write(studentdata)
    return file


command = input('Please enter a command: ')
while command:
    if command == '6':
        print('Have a good day!')
        exit()
    elif command == '1': # opt 1
        print('\n')
        askclass = input('Please enter your class: ')
        studentno = int(input('How many student\'s are in your class?: '))
        data = {}
        for i in range(0,studentno):
            askstudent = input('Please enter a student\'s full name: ')
            askscore = int(input('Please enter the student\'s score: '))
            data[askstudent] = askscore
            print('\n')
            print('Student Added!')
            createClass(askclass,data)
        command = input('Please enter a command: ')
```

Now, I am trying to create a function which allows you to edit the scores of any student.

To do this, I am trying to create a list which contains every student's name and score from each line using the .split attribute and then turning that list into a dictionary. So far I have come up with this:

```
def convertList(listname):
    iteration = iter(listname) 
    resultant = dict(zip(iteration, iteration)) 
    return resultant

def editStudent(classfile, selectedstudent, newscore):
    with open(f'Class {classfile}.txt', '+w') as chosen:
        for line in chosen:
            listver = line.split(',')
        data = convertList(listver)
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == 'Name: ' + str(selectedstudent):
                formattedresult = 'Score: {}/100'.format(newscore)
                value.replace(value, formattedresult)
                final = print('New result is ' + newscore + '/100')
                return final

if command == '3':
        whichfile = input('Which class would you like to edit?: ')
        whichstudent = input('Which student would you like to edit?: ')
        whichscore = input('Please enter the updated score: ')
        editStudent(whichfile,whichstudent,whichscore)
        command = input('Please enter a command: ')
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sinclair_ma/Desktop/IST AT1/testing.py", line 90, in <module>
    editStudent(whichfile,whichstudent,whichscore)
  File "/Users/sinclair_ma/Desktop/IST AT1/testing.py", line 48, in editStudent
    data = convertList(listver)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'listver' referenced before assignment
```

I have a feeling that I am going the wrong way about trying to replace the values, but I'm having trouble figuring out any alternatives. Any help would be much appreciated to get me in the correct direction.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if in function you want to assign to global variable then you have to use word `global` to inform function to use global variable instead of creating local variable.

Comment: I think you have wrong indentations. You run `listver = line.split(',')` inside `for`-loop but later you use `data = convertList(listver)` outside loop so it can be run only with last `listver` or when there is no `listver`.